# 404 not found - Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I am getting 404 not found when returning view from my controller.
This is web.php :

```
Route::get('/', [MoviesController::class, 'index'])->name('movies.index');
Route::get('/movies/{movie}', [MoviesController::class, 'show'])->name('movies.show')
```

This is the controller function :

```
public function show($id)
{

    $movie = Http::withToken(config('services.tmdb.token'))
        ->get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'.$id)
        ->json();

    dump($movie);

    return view('show', [
        'movie' => $movie,
    ]);
}
```

And here is how i am linking it in my blade file :

```
<a href="{{ route('movies.show', $movie['id']) }}">
```

i have checked

```
php artisan route:list
```

and the route exists.
** Laravel version : 8.x

Comment: i am getting laravel 404 error. I am getting the preferred linbk : http://localhost/MovieDemo2/Public/movies/671039 but my show.blade is not showing instead i am getting " 404 | Not Found "

Comment: /Public doesn't look correct

Comment: Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Normally the folder name would be lowercase. Are you creating a virtual host for your app? Try "php artisan serve" to see if you still get a 404.

Comment: @Thomas thank you very much. I made "Public" to "public" and it worked. I can't believe I was stuck here for 2 hours -_-

Comment: URI is case sensitive,  so this is a silly mistake.

Comment: @Tahmid cool man

Comment: @sta http://localhost/MovieDemo2/Public/ this link works, that's why I didn't give any thought to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My url was wrong.
I changed it from  "localhost/MovieDemo2/Public/movies/671039"
To  "localhost/MovieDemo2/public/movies/671039"
Silly mistake.